# Inconsistency with 'show' function

Tags: laravel

I've been working on a project for a few months now and I feel like I am seeing some inconsistency with how the public function show is working

I have a model and controller for a *Location* that has

```
public function show(Location $Location)
{
    $Loc = Location::with('company:id,name')->findOrFail($Location); 
    return response()->json($Loc,200);
}
```

and that works just fine. Note the parameters.

I just made a new model and controller for *Asset* and it has this:

```
public function show(Asset $asset)
{ 
    $AssetReturn = Asset::with('location:id,name,address')->findOrFail($asset);
    return response()->json($AssetReturn,200);
}
```

but that does not work. it just returns empty. If i remove the class name from the parameters so its just

```
public function show($asset)
```

then it works as intended.

relation from asset model to location:

```
public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you put here Asset and Location models as well? I mean 'company' and 'location' relationships at least

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding), Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name. For example:

```
Route::get('/assets/{asset}', function (App\Asset $asset) {
    $asset->load('location:id,name,address');
    return response()->json($asset);
});
```

Since the `$asset` variable is type-hinted as the `App\Asset` Eloquent model and the variable name matches the `{asset}` URI segment, Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated.

If you don't want this behavior and want to use `findOrFail` manually:

```php
Route::get('/assets/{asset}', function ($assetId) {
    $asset = App\Asset::with('location:id,name,address')->findOrFail($assetId);
    return response()->json($asset);
});
```

Comment: I'm using a resource route. it looks like this:
Route::resource('asset','AssetController');